# Use ffmpeg to create a music video with the cover on a black background

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use this tutorial to create youtube videos with ffmpeg
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube

When using this example, I get a video that works however the background is white

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i albumcover.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

I tried to add a color filter but that makes the whole video output black:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i albumcover.png -filter_complex "color=s=1920x1080:c=black" -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

I find it very difficult to find something about this on the internet as most ask for just a black video or a transparent background for a gif ect.

So how do I get the albumcover.png on a black background?

EDIT: I just realized that the video format is of course the image format (square) and therefore it's white on youtube. The question therefore is now how do I create a black background 16:9 and put the albumcover centered on it...

Answer (score 1):

Overlay the image onto a black canvas.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=r=2:d=1 -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i albumcover.png -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=oh*16/9:ih[bg][img];[bg][img]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M output.mkv`

Due to some nuances with -shortest, I've added some options to ensure output terminates with the shortest stream.